# Time series in Finite State Space Markov chain

Tags: matlab, time-series, markov-chains

I have state transition probability matrix for state K=8,

trans =

```
0.9245    0.0755         0         0         0         0         0         0
0.0176    0.9399    0.0425         0         0         0         0         0
     0    0.0290    0.9263    0.0447         0         0         0         0
     0         0    0.0465    0.9228    0.0307         0         0         0
     0         0         0    0.0731    0.8979    0.0290         0         0
     0         0         0         0    0.0907    0.8857    0.0236         0
     0         0         0         0         0    0.1080    0.8750    0.0170
     0         0         0         0         0         0    0.1250    0.8750
```

I need to generate time vector/time series from the transition matrix using Matlab. Can anyone suggest me on how to generate the time series from this state transition probability matrix in Matlab.

Comment: did the solution below work?

Comment: @HarshalPandya I already have the code u have given, but unfortunately this dosen't work for my case. My question is i need to generate the time series vector from the transition matrix. Here i don't find time series vector.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isn't a time series just a vector of successive samples of states given the transition probabilities and initial state. If so then in the below code setting T=100 would give you a vector of length 100 in the chain, which would be your time series.

Comment: @HarshalPandya I have a question for u, i have generated the time seires as u told but i need to know how to generate the probability density function from this time series? your help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If by generate you mean sample from the transition matrix this should work:

```
function [chain,state] = simulate_markov(x,P,pi0,T); 
%% x = the quantity corresponding to each state, typical element x(i) 
%% P = Markov transition matrix, typical element p(i,j) i,j=1,...n 
%% pi0 = probability distribution over initial state 
%% T = number of periods to simulate 
%% 
%% chain = sequence of realizations from the simulation 
%% Modification of progam by L&S. 
n = length(x); %% what is the size of the state vector? 
E = rand(T,1); %% T-vector of draws from independent uniform [0,1] 
cumsumP = P*triu(ones(size(P))); 
 %% creates a matrix whose rows are the cumulative sums of 
 %% the rows of P 
%%%%% SET INITIAL STATE USING pi0 
E0 = rand(1,1); 
ppi0 = [0,cumsum(pi0)]; 
s0 = ((E0<=ppi0(2:n+1)).*(E0>ppi0(1:n)))'; 
s = s0; 
%%%%% ITERATE ON THE CHAIN 
for t=1:T, 
 state(:,t) = s; 
 ppi = [0,s'*cumsumP]; 
 s = ((E(t)<=ppi(2:n+1)).*(E(t)>ppi(1:n)))'; 
end 
chain = x'*state;
```

Source : http://www-scf.usc.edu/~ngarnold/Markov%20Chains%20Notes.pdf